# tangent line to the graph

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

this is the problem, I reached pi/6 & -pi/6 each time yet the website is saying my answer is incorrect.

steps i took.

1) derivative of 4t-3tant/4t+3tant 
2)yeilds 4+3sec^2(x) on bottom 
3) set to 0
4) get +/-= sec = sort(-4/3) 
5) cos = sqrt(3) /2 which => pi/6 or -pi/6

??? any ideas where I'm messing up? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{dx}{dt}=4+3\sec^2 t$. This is never $0$.

**Remark:** Note that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$. You appear to be trying to find instead the derivative of $\frac{y}{x}$.

You do seem, however, to end up with $4+3\sec^2 t$, and set this equal to $0$.  Note there is no such thing (in the reals) as $\sqrt{-4/3}$. It is clear without calculation that $4+3\sec^2 x$ is always greater than $4$, indeed $\ge 7$.

Comment: so does that make it no values of t as it can't ever reach that value without imaginary numbers? Im not sure what to do instead of setting it to 0

Comment: If you really want to, set it equal to $0$. But then you have to solve the equation correctly. You did, sort of, getting a term $\sqrt{-4/3}$, which is not a real number. So there is no solution, just like the equation $4+t^2=0$ has no solution. I prefer to observe that $4+3\sec^2 t$ is obviously always positive, so is never equal to $0$.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense, thank you for the help!